# Edit button not working properly after adding 'Add' button in the gridview footer

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I have just added an 'add' button in my grid view after previously having an Edit that includes the Update button as well, however after adding the 'Add' button that works perfectly fine with the added record viewing in the gridview and in the database, the Edit button does not seem to work anymore. Here is the script for the buttons.

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="6" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"   

    OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" Height="226px" Width="1172px" ShowFooter="True"  HorizontalAlign="Center">

              <Columns> 
                <asp:TemplateField>  
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" Font-Size="Medium" Height="32px" Width="68px" />          
                   </ItemTemplate> 
                <EditItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Update" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"/>  
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"/>  
                </EditItemTemplate> 
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="newAddBtn" runat="server"  
  OnClick="NewAddBtn_Click" Text="Add"  CommandName="Insert" Font-Size="Medium" Height="32px" Width="64px"/>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Class ID">  
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CID" runat="server" 
     Text='<%#Eval("CID") %>'></asp:Label>  

                </ItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>  
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Class Name">  
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="newName" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Power Yoga</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Pilates</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Cardio Peak</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Body Attack</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Corb</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Boxing</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Zumba</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Weights</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NameErr" runat="server" 
  ControlToValidate="newName" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red">
       </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_cName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CName") %>'></asp:Label>  
                </ItemTemplate>  
                <EditItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:TextBox ID="cname_txt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CName") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                </EditItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>  
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Class Start Time">  
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="newStart" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="startErr" runat="server" ControlToValidate="newStart" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_cstart" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CStart") %>'></asp:Label>  
                </ItemTemplate>  
                <EditItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:TextBox ID="cstart_txt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("cStart") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                </EditItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField> 

                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Class Finish Time">  
                      <FooterTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="newEnd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="endErr" runat="server" ControlToValidate="newEnd" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                      </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_cend" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("cend") %>'></asp:Label>  
                </ItemTemplate>  
                <EditItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:TextBox ID="cend_txt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("cend") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                </EditItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>             
        </Columns>  
              <FooterStyle BackColor="#663300" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#663300" ForeColor="#ffffff"/>  
        <RowStyle BackColor="#e7ceb6"/>  
    </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the code behind the "Add" button, after the connection has been opened to the database.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ShowData();
        }
    }
    //ShowData method for Displaying Data in Gridview  
    protected void ShowData()
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        con.Open();

        // adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from customers", con);

        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from classes", con);

        adapt.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        con.Close();
    }

        Control control = null;
        if (GridView1.FooterRow != null)
        {
            control = GridView1.FooterRow;
        }
        else
        {
            control = GridView1.Controls[0].Controls[0];
        }

       string className = ((DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("newName")).SelectedItem.Text;

       // string className = (GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("newName") as TextBox).Text;
        string startTime = (GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("newStart") as TextBox).Text;
        string endTime = (GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("newEnd") as TextBox).Text;
        //  string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strcon"].ConnectionString;
        //  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))


                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO classes VALUES(@cName, @cStart, @cEnd)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cName", className);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cStart", startTime);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cEnd", endTime);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();


     //   Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that at the end of Add operation, your gridview is databound as in code snippet below, i.e. just after `con.Close();` line of code in your C# code.

I am assuming you have a method for getting gridviewdata.

```
GridView1.DataSource =  GetGridData();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Also, make sure all validators in your footer have a ValidationGroup="Add"else when you click on Edit button in grid row, it will prevent from page postback due to the footer validators. Also, add ValidationGroup="Add" for the Add button also.

```
<FooterTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="newEnd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="endErr" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Add" 
       ControlToValidate="newEnd" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: The edit button still does not function properly, when I click on it there is no outcome it's like clicking in the void

Comment: Yes I did, it adds the record but still the Edit button does not work

Comment: Can you paste the full grid view html? It seems there is something missing. Make sure you have RowUpdating event for gridview subscribed.

Comment: Kindly look at my update question, it reflects everything now. @Sunil

Comment: Show code for  RowUpdating and RowEditing event also. There must be issues there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159317/discussion-between-scarl-and-sunil).